# select a particular string from a semi-colon delimited list

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, parsing, split, csv

I want to extract a string which has semi-colon as a delimiter. I tried using Substring, Charindex and Left function. But I'm not able to get the desired result. Below is my select statement. Output result must be "Unsure how to perform task.  Meter read 10 in office before testing". Thanks

```
Declare @string Varchar(max)='Sampling:45;Traveling:30;CalibratedNo;uncalibratedReason:: ' +
                             'Unsure how to perform task.  Meter read 10 in office before ' +
                             'testing.;pH1:6.5;pH2:6.5;Dis.Oxygen1:7.4'

Select SubString(@string, (CHARINDEX('uncalibratedReason:', @string, 0) + 19), 
  (CharIndex('uncalibratedReason:', LEFT(@string, (LEN(@string) -
  (CharIndex(';', @string, 0)))), 0) - 0)) As New
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shnugo anwser very cool. (UpVote)

However, this UDF Parser returns the sequence and value

```
Declare @string Varchar(max)='Sampling:45;Traveling:30;CalibratedNo;uncalibratedReason:: ' +
                             'Unsure how to perform task.  Meter read 10 in office before ' +
                             'testing.;pH1:6.5;pH2:6.5;Dis.Oxygen1:7.4'

Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse](@String,';')
  --Where Key_PS = 5
  --Where Key_Value Like '%:%'
  --Where Key_Value Like 'pH1%'
```

Returns

```
Key_PS  Key_Value
1       Sampling:45
2       Traveling:30
3       CalibratedNo
4       uncalibratedReason:: Unsure how to perform task.  Meter read 10 in office before testing.
5       pH1:6.5
6       pH2:6.5
7       Dis.Oxygen1:7.4
```

The UDF

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse] (@String varchar(max),@Delimeter varchar(10))
--Usage: Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('Dog,Cat,House,Car',',')
--       Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('John Cappelletti was here',' ')

Returns @ReturnTable Table (Key_PS int IDENTITY(1,1), Key_Value varchar(max))
As
Begin
   Declare @XML xml;Set @XML = Cast('<x>' + Replace(@String,@Delimeter,'</x><x>')+'</x>' as XML)
   Insert Into @ReturnTable Select ltrim(rtrim(String.value('.', 'varchar(max)'))) FROM @XML.nodes('x') as T(String)
   Return 
End
```

Comment: Hi, if you like my answer, you might want to see my `UPDATE 2` :-) And if you want to read about a method to get this mehtod save, even if your string is carrying forbidden characters, you might want to read my answer at the question which is linked as duplicate :-)

Comment: @Shnugo Even better.  I've got a Love/Hate relationship with SO.   Love how I can learn something new and help others.  Hate how dumb it makes  me feels when I see stuff like that.

Answer (score 3):

Try it like this:

```
Declare @string Varchar(max) = 'Sampling:45;Traveling:30;CalibratedNo;uncalibratedReason:Unsure how to perform task.  Meter read 10 in office before testing.;pH1:6.5;pH2:6.5;Dis.Oxygen1:7.4';

SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(@string,';','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML).value('x[4]','nvarchar(max)')
```

The result is:

```
uncalibratedReason:Unsure how to perform task.  Meter read 10 in office before testing.
```

You can take away the leading `uncalibratedReason:`  simply with `SUBSTRING` and `CHARINDEX` looking for `:` if you need this.

### UPDATE

Here is the full code:

```
DECLARE @result NVARCHAR(MAX)=
(SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(@string,';','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML).value('x[4]','nvarchar(max)'));

SELECT SUBSTRING(@result,CHARINDEX(':',@result)+1,10000)
```

### UPDATE 2: Find position by starting string

```
DECLARE @result NVARCHAR(MAX)=
(SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(@string,';','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML).value('(x[substring(.,1,string-length("uncalibratedReason:")) eq "uncalibratedReason:"])[1]','nvarchar(max)'));

SELECT SUBSTRING(@result,CHARINDEX(':',@result)+1,10000)
```

### UPDATE 3 The ultimative solution :-)

```
Declare @string Varchar(max) = 'Sampling:45;Traveling:30;CalibratedNo;uncalibratedReason:Unsure how to perform task.  Meter read 10 in office before testing.;pH1:6.5;pH2:6.5;Dis.Oxygen1:7.4';


WITH Casted(ThePart) AS
(
    SELECT Node.value('.','nvarchar(max)')
    FROM
    (
    SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(@string,';','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML)
    ) AS tbl(AsXML)
    CROSS APPLY AsXML.nodes('/x') AS The(Node)
)
,Splitted(SpecificPart) AS
(
    SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(ThePart,':','</x><x>') + '</x>'  AS XML) 
    FROM Casted
)
SELECT SpecificPart.value('x[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS Caption
      ,SpecificPart.value('x[2]','nvarchar(max)') AS Data
FROM Splitted
```

The result

```
Caption             Data
CalibratedNo        NULL
Dis.Oxygen1         7.4
pH1                 6.5
pH2                 6.5
Sampling            45
Traveling           30
uncalibratedReason  Unsure how to perform task.  Meter read 10 in office before testing.
```

Comment: Appreciate your response. What if the field is not always at 4 ? That string might be in 3'rd field or 7'th field.

Comment: How would you know where to search? Is the string always starting with `uncalibratedReason:`?

Comment: Currently i'm only interested to extract the string for uncalibratedReason. But it doesnt always starts on 4'th. Example some strings doesn't have fields such as sampling or Traveling.

Comment: In this case you'd have to dive a bit deeper into `XQuery`. See my update

Comment: Thanks, both your solutions worked. It was nice to learn how to segregate the strings using xml.